# Access google storage from compute instance with no external IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-api

I need to read and write to a google storage from my vm with no public IP. It has a disk with a custom image with everything I need: python etc.

I create an instance with a script like [this one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/api/create_instance.py). In the `config` dictionary you can see the section `networkInterfaces` where I specify that I don't want a public IP for my machine.

I paste the section here with my configuration:

```
# Specify a network interface with NAT to access the public
# internet.
'networkInterfaces': [            
        {
        "kind": "compute#networkInterface",
        "subnetwork": "projects/PROJECT-NAME/regions/europe-west3/subnetworks/default",
        "aliasIpRanges": []
        }
],
```

The problem is that this setup doesn't even allow me to write neither read from google storage within the same project. Just fyi a `ping www.google.com` does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to activate the private Google access on the subnet where is deployed your VM.

Go to VPC menu, select your VPC and the subnet on which your VM is deployed. Then edit it and activate the private Google access

[image]